# DES signature confusion

Tags: encryption, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature, des

I was recently examining a file containing cleartext, then under the cleartext:

```
This is cleartext. A message presumably signed with the below certificate.

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
Modulus: 31353732
DEK-Info: DES-CBC,656e733333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zJZkhn==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I googled DES-CBC and found that it was a symmetric key algorithm. From this information, through bruteforce, could the original secret key be found and the encrypted data be decrypted to cleartext? How about re-encrypted to yield the same encrypted text?

Comment: DES has 56 bit long key, so it is [possible](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24195/calculation-of-time-needed-to-crack-des-with-my-cpu) to bruteforce the key. Question is, if it's feasible for you.  What I see confusing is - the content is designed as encrypted certificate (?), not any private key.

Comment: I've never seen an encrypted certificate so I don't know what's going on here. There's no reason to encrypt a certificate, everything in it is supposed to be public. Note that anybody or any piece of software can create a file with any header they want to. Also, certificates contain public keys and public keys are used to verifying signatures, not signing things.

Comment: Is this part of a capture-the-flag contest or some other challenge?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Look at PKCS#12, where the certificates are generally also encrypted (usually with RC2, talk about aging algorithms). I was designing an alternative, but my attention to it dwindled as I didn't need it anymore.